# Where should daemon status files go in the *nix hierarchy?

Tags: linux, daemon, unix-philosophy

This is kind of a canonical question about the Unix/Linux filesystem.

I am working on a little daemon that generates output like this every five minutes:

```
Data1: 100
Data2: 201
Data3: 102
```

This data needs to be accessed by another system, so I am going to store it in a little file that the other system can access.  In the *nix hierarchy is there a spot where little files that tell the current status of daemons go?  I'm considering just putting it in `/tmp/` unless I get a better spot.

Comment: note also, `/run` is often a tmpfs so your data stays in virtual memory rather being written to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historically small transient files go to `/var` or `/var/run` but lately some distros dropped `/var/run` and started using just `/run`, thats the reason most if not all linux programs write their logs to `/var/log`, usually there is a directory inside with the name of the application leaving you with `/var/your_app/data_file.txt`

`/var/run` or `/run` contain files that are present only while the program is running.

So if your daemon will delete the file when it is stopped and create it every time it is started go with `/run`, but if your file will remain even after the daemon is stopped go with `/var`